# Delete item "Object required" excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, dynamic

I understand what the problem is, but i don't have a clue on how to solve it...
So what I am doing is that I click on a button (addSceneButton) in my worksheet("costing") and it is going to insert a copy of another sheet("Scene Template") just above of the button (addSceneButton). It is also gonna create a button (deleteSceneButton) at the rightmost of the previously inserted sheet. 
This button (deleteSceneButton), when clicked, must delete the region next to it.
It works ok if I only add 1 scene. But when I add more then one and then click on the deleteButton, it will automatically delete the last sheet inserted. 
And when I want to delete a second one, it gives me the "Object Required" Error. 
It must be because I overwrite the delteButtonPos instead of creating one dynamically but I dont know how. 
Could someone help me on this ?

Here is my code

```
Public buttonPos As Range
Public deleteButtonPos As Range
Public deleteButton As Object

Private Sub AddSceneButton_Click()

    Set buttonPos = Sheets(AddSceneButton.Parent.Name).Cells(AddSceneButton.TopLeftCell.Row - 1, _
                                             AddSceneButton.TopLeftCell.Column)
    Sheets("Scene Template").Activate
    Sheets("Scene Template").Select
    Sheets("Scene Template").Range("A1:H22").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Costing").Select
    buttonPos.Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown

    'Insert the Add Scene Button


    'Insert the Delete Button
    Set deleteButtonPos = Selection.Range("H1")
    Set deleteButton = ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(deleteButtonPos.Left, _
                                               deleteButtonPos.Top, _
                                               deleteButtonPos.Width, _
                                               deleteButtonPos.Height)
    With deleteButton
        .Caption = "Delete Button"
        .Name = "deleteButtonFunct"
        .OnAction = "Sheet1.deleteButtonFunct_Click"
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub deleteButtonFunct_Click()
    deleteButtonPos.Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Delete
    buttonPos.Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you share a copy of your workbook?

Comment: @NickSlash How can I do that ?

Comment: You'd need to upload it somewhere and provide a link, dropbox etc

Comment: Well for those who tried to help me thank you :) I have manage to make it works, I used the function Application.Caller to setup my delete position direcly in my deleteButtonFunc. with this it was easy to simply take a range near it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why your code is throwing object required is because it cannot find the Button. So to correct that we need to set the button again after the first deletion.

Here I have added 3 more variables as public `introw, selnum, colnum`.

There is no change in the **AddSceneButton** sub part.

I have added an additional **Check** function to set the button again and to set the row number and column number correctly.

Check function is called within **deleteButtonFunct** sub, so that everytime when the delete button is clicked, it deletes the current/latest rows which is copied
to the sheet and sets a new delete button to the last column.

And if the `Row number is 1`, then there is no need to set an additional button, hence the condition inside the check function.

I have modified your code. Please find the updated code.

```
Public buttonPos As Range
Public deleteButtonPos As Range
Public deleteButton As Object
Public introw, selnum, colnum As Integer


Private Sub AddSceneButton_Click()

    Set buttonPos = Sheets(AddSceneButton.Parent.Name).Cells(AddSceneButton.TopLeftCell.Row - 1, _
                                             AddSceneButton.TopLeftCell.Column)
    Sheets("Scene Template").Activate
    Sheets("Scene Template").Select
    Sheets("Scene Template").Range("A1:H22").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Costing").Select
    buttonPos.Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown

    'Insert the Add Scene Button


    'Insert the Delete Button
    Set deleteButtonPos = Selection.Range("H1")
    Set deleteButton = ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(deleteButtonPos.Left, _
                                               deleteButtonPos.Top, _
                                               deleteButtonPos.Width, _
                                               deleteButtonPos.Height)
    With deleteButton
        .Caption = "Delete Button"
        .Name = "deleteButtonFunct"
        .OnAction = "Sheet1.deleteButtonFunct_Click"
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub deleteButtonFunct_Click()

    deleteButtonPos.Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    introw = Selection.Count
    Selection.EntireRow.Delete
    buttonPos.Select
    Call check

End Sub

Function check()

rownum = ActiveCell.Row
colnum = ActiveCell.Column
selnum = rownum - introw

If (rownum > 1) Then
Cells(selnum, colnum).Select

    Set deleteButtonPos = Selection.Range("H1")
    Set deleteButton = ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(deleteButtonPos.Left, _
                                               deleteButtonPos.Top, _
                                               deleteButtonPos.Width, _
                                               deleteButtonPos.Height)
    With deleteButton
        .Caption = "Delete Button"
        .Name = "deleteButtonFunct"
        .OnAction = "Sheet1.deleteButtonFunct_Click"
    End With
End If

End Function
```

The code is tested and is working fine.
Hope this should help :)

Comment: Hi and thanks for the reply, I haven't try it yet but just a question, wouldn't that always delete the last scene add ?

Comment: No. if you have a range of data (`last scene`) and a Delete button on the last cell, when you press the Delete button, it will only delete that range of data (`last scene`), it wont touch any other range of data(`last scene`). 
So it is actually independent of when the range of data (`last scene`) is added, whether first or last. when you click first delete button on top right cell, it will delete that range of data (`last scene`) alone.

I have checked with different range of data (`last scene`) and verified the functionality. 

Please let me know if any clarification is required :)

Comment: My I managed to do was pretty similar to that in fact :) Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The range variables `buttonPos` and `deleteButtonPos` only ever seem to contain a single cell ref. When you add the 2nd scene you need to add another cell to the range using the `Application.Union()` method. You'll need some way to associate the scenes to the respective delete  button.

Comment: thanks for the reply, this would act just like a list would, which is not so bad :) The best would be to use a map I think so that I can pair my button with my range.

Answer (score 0):

If you add the following code to a new module, it shows how you can uniquely handle all your dynamic buttons.

My example uses a number (count) to track and index the new buttons, it could be modified fairly simply to be a cell reference (to range you want to delete in your example).

```
Public Count As Integer ' Used to index the controls in my example

Sub addButton()
Dim P As Range: Set P = Selection
Dim B As Object
Dim S As String: S = CStr(Count) ' string representation of count

Set B = ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(P.Left, P.Top, P.Width, P.Height)

With B
    .Caption = "Id#" & S
    .Name = "Id" & S
    .onAction = "'onAction " & Chr(34) & S & Chr(34) & "'"
End With

Count = Count + 1 ' Increase the counter

End Sub

Public Sub onAction(ByVal Index As String)
MsgBox "You Pressed Button #" & Index & "!", vbOKOnly, "Action"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, just to be sure but the chr(34) is the quote " " mark ?
I will try this and see if that works. Ah and just to be sure but my function isnt in a modules but directly in the button "click" function, is that ok ?

Comment: `Chr(34)` is a double quote yes, your button click function is probably in the correct sort of module already. If you look in the project explorer there will probably be a entry called "module1" in the modules branch.